# Classifying this Partial Differential Equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following partial differential equation:

$u_{xx} + 2u_{yy} + u_{zz} - 2u_{xy} - 2u_{yz} = 0$

To my knowledge, when classifying a partial differential equation, you analyze the equation that parallels the form:

$Au_{xx} + Bu_{xy} + Cu_{yy} + Du_x + Eu_y + Fu + G = 0$

Then, analyze the following expression,

$B^2 - 4AC$

A term less than zero $\rightarrow$ Elliptic

A term greater than zero $\rightarrow$ Hyperbolic

A term equal to zero $\rightarrow$ Parabolic

In the previous example:

$A = 1$

$B = -2$

$C = 2$

And $B^2 - 4AC = -4$ which would be elliptical. However, my professor's notes say that this is a parabolic equation. Am I missing something?

Comment: yes, $B^2 - 4AC$ is only when you have a diffenrial equation of one variable and of degree 2 : $A u_{xx} + B u_{x} + u = f$. here you have a ([characteristic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_(calculus))) polynomial with two variables : $A X^2 + B XY + C Y^2 + DX + EY + F$ which is the polynomial that you would get by applying to your equation the Laplace/Fourier transform (with $X = i\omega_x$and $Y = i \omega_y$ the 2-dimensional Fourier variables)

Comment: but for solving $Au_{xx} + Bu_{xy} + Cu_{yy} + Du_x + Eu_y + Fu + G = 0$ an homogeneous linear differential equation, the method is the same : find the solutions of the form $u = e^{i ax+ i by}$, solve for $a,b$, and you'll get the general form or your solutions as linear combinations of such pure exponentials solutions.

Comment: But is that transformation really necessary?

Comment: ? did you read my last comment ? and yes the Laplace/Fourier transform and the concept of convolution operator is really necessary for understanding non-homogeneous linear differential equations.

Comment: (and a mistake : there is no $G$ in an homogeneous equation, the equivalent of the constant term is $F u$ (the $0$th derivative), with $G \ne 0$ it's not homogenous anymore since it is of the form $\sum \alpha_{..} \ \partial_{..} u = f$ with $f \ne 0$)